# Python Introspection with Object Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.6

I'm working with an older version of python, 2.6.5. I can use dir to see what members an object has but I'd like to differentiate among the members in an object versus the members inherited from a parent class.

```
class Parent(object):

    def parent_method1(self):  
        return 1

    def parent_method2(self):
        return 2

class Child(Parent):

    def child_method1(self):
        return 1
```

Is there a way to inspect (i.e. dir) an instance of Child object and distinguish which methods are from the Child class and which are inherited from the Parent class?

Comment: The precise version of Python doesn't matter in this specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `dir()` does not give that distinction.

You'd have to manually traverse the [class MRO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) and produce the list yourself:

```
def dir_with_context(cls):
    for c in cls.__mro__:
        for name in sorted(c.__dict__):
            yield (c, name)
```

This produces:

```
>>> list(dir_with_context(Child))
[(<class '__main__.Child'>, '__doc__'), (<class '__main__.Child'>, '__module__'), (<class '__main__.Child'>, 'child_method1'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, '__dict__'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, '__doc__'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, '__module__'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, '__weakref__'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, 'parent_method1'), (<class '__main__.Parent'>, 'parent_method2'), (<type 'object'>, '__class__'), (<type 'object'>, '__delattr__'), (<type 'object'>, '__doc__'), (<type 'object'>, '__format__'), (<type 'object'>, '__getattribute__'), (<type 'object'>, '__hash__'), (<type 'object'>, '__init__'), (<type 'object'>, '__new__'), (<type 'object'>, '__reduce__'), (<type 'object'>, '__reduce_ex__'), (<type 'object'>, '__repr__'), (<type 'object'>, '__setattr__'), (<type 'object'>, '__sizeof__'), (<type 'object'>, '__str__'), (<type 'object'>, '__subclasshook__')]
```

The function can easily be augmented to skip names already seen in a subclass:

```
def dir_with_context(cls):
    seen = set()
    for c in cls.__mro__:
        for name in sorted(c.__dict__):
            if name not in seen:
                yield (c, name)
                seen.add(name)
```

at which point it produces the exact same number of entries as `dir(Child)`, except for the order the names appear in (the above groups them per class):

```
>>> sorted(name for c, name in dir_with_context(Child)) == dir(Child)
True
```